# Does the end determine the center of a coend?

Tags: category-theory

For distributors,if coends composes, does the end determine the center of such trace? More generally I guess, what is the end of a coend?

Comment: Please edit to add several more details. Introduce notation to make clear exactly which end you’re comparing to exactly which coend, and which sense of “center” you’re using. Ideally, you would also say something about where this problem arose, or why you believe such a result might be true.

Comment: By the center I would mean the universal subobject  related to an end (ends, per nlab entry. picks out a universal subobject on which the left and right action coincides). Say we have a parameterized coend say at x, will the end pick out a universal object related to x?

Answer (score 1):

This request of clarification is too long to be a comment. :)

In case you're asking what is the end 
$$
\int_A\int^B P(A,B)\times Q(B,A)
$$
for two composable profunctors $P,Q$ (necessarily in opposite directions)... no one knows in the general case. In some concrete cases, you can say something, for example if $P=Q=id$.

In general, this is a result of the kind "what is the limit of this colimit, and how does it relate to the colimit of the limit?". This kind of questions is notoriously difficult.